# pexpect output is out of order

Tags: python, output, pexpect

Sorry if this is a dumb quesiton, This is my first attempt at python.  I wrote a script that reads a list of interfaces from a file, logs into cisco 7600's and then calls a function that pulls the status and running-config of the interfaces.  I run 2 commands on each interface.  The problem is managing the pexpect output.  Some of the interfaces it does exactly what I expect (no pun intended) and others, it doesn't seem to wait for any ouput at all, still others  the output from one command ends up showing up after 2 or three other interfaces have been checked.  Right now I just have it all outputting to sys.stdout.  Once I get it working I will write it out to a file.  I've tried using sendline instead of send, I've played with child.timeout, child.maxsize, time.sleep ... I can post output upon request.  I'm just trying to keep this from being too long.  The code I am having issues with is:

```
def get_int_conf(child, if_file, dev_type, prompt):
  open_file = "/home/" + if_file

  if dev_type == 'cisco':
      child.logfile = sys.stdout
      with open(open_file, 'r') as int_list:
#
#Pull name from list
#
          for int_name in int_list:
              print "Interface name is %s" % (int_name)
#
#Build correct syntax
#
              match1 = re.search("(Gi|Te)", int_name)
              match2 = re.search("[0-9]+/[0-9]+", int_name)
              if match1 and match2:
                  first_match = match1.group(1)
                  second_match = match2.group()
                  short_nm = first_match + second_match + " \n"
#
# Run show interface status commmand
#
              child.send('sh interface status | in ' + short_nm)
              child.expect(prompt)
              child.send('\n')
#
# Run show run interface command
#
              child.send('sh run interface ' + int_name)
              child.expect(prompt)
              child.send('\n')
  return()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `child` is created and used outside the function I'd first make sure it first gets into a "known state", then just alternate sendline and expect statements. Something along these lines used to work for me on a 7600:

```
child.sendline('term len 0')  # if not already done, else just child.sendline('')
child.expect(prompt)
...
for int_name in int_list:
    ...
    child.sendline('sh interface status | in ' + short_nm)
    child.expect(prompt)
    child.sendline('sh run interface ' + int_name)
    child.expect(prompt)
```

Maybe stupid, but I'd also check the order of the interfaces in  `open_file`.

Side note: you have access to the string buffers containing what pexpect receives before and after the matched pattern in each `child.expect()` statement with the following constructs which you can print/process at will:

```
print child.before
print child.after
```

You might want to get familiar with them - they're your friends during development/debugging, maybe you can even use them in the actual script implementation.